# Microphone is detected, but no input from it

Tags: audio, alsa, pop-os, microphone, recording

I am currently using Pop!_OS version 22.04 LTS. I was trying to get on a Discord call with a friend, but he couldn't hear me. I later discovered that it would detect audio out as the input.

I went to settings to find out that it was not detecting my headphone mic for the input, even though it said it was. I tried everything online from using `pavucontrol`, `hdajackretask`, `alsamixer`, and resetting the audio manager, following instructions on the Pop!_OS audio page. After doing this, it doesn't detect audio at all, and there is no system audio either. Under `pavucontrol` it shows that it is plugged in (which it is), but no audio from the mic.

Nothing seems to work, and the only way to use a mic is to plug in a USB-C headset with a built in mic. Is there any way to resolve this?

Comment: I have the same issue. Did if you find any workaround?

Comment: I still have this issue, but I have been using a usb mic. I have also found that any usb type mic works. Only my built in microphone doesn't work.